# Detection for Safari Windows with Javascript

Tags: javascript, safari, browser-detection

How do I check if user is using Safari on the Windows? Because I need to apply some special styles to the site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test `navigator.userAgent` for the strings `Safari/` and `Windows` ([list of Safari user agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/)), e.g.: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/kepan/1)

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (ua.indexOf("safari/") !== -1 &&  // It says it's Safari
    ua.indexOf("windows") !== -1 &&  // It says it's on Windows
    ua.indexOf("chrom")   === -1     // It DOESN'T say it's Chrome/Chromium
    ) {
    // Looks like Safari on Windows (but browser detection is unreliable and best avoided)
}
```

...but *browser* detection is usually not the best solution to a problem. Much better, where you can, to use *feature* detection. You can feature-detect nearly everything. Kangax has [a great list of feature detects](http://kangax.github.com/cft/), and of course libs like [Moderizr](http://modernizr.com/) do them as well. But I don't know your use-case...

Answer (score 0):

This plugin seems to be exactly what you want. [Plugin Link](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/07/16/jquery-browser-and-os-detection-plugin/)

On the plugin page they link to a test page that runs the plugin which will shoot back the browser and OS. [Test Link](http://stoimen.com/jquery.client.plugin/)