# Safari inline-block not floating

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm using the following HTML and CSS to create elements which are tightly together in a 100% space (floating?).

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image">This is image</div>
    <div class="content">This is content</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
font-size: 0;
}
.image, .content {
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 50%;
color: #000;
font-size: 18px;
}
.image {
background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnu8ps0t/1/).

Endresult: Chrome top, Safari for Windows bottom

[image]

This style works great on all browsers - except Safari for Windows. I'm not sure about the "real" Safari but my iPad seems to work fine. Is this an issue I should be worried about?

Comment: Safari on windows isn't up to date with most modern browsers, there-fore you will get problems. Don't worry as safari on Mac and other apple products it works perfectly

Comment: Thank you for the info. Solutions exist but since the issue is not replicated in the real version I won't go through the trouble of fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Safari for Windows, setting the width to:

```
width: 49.7%;
```

will give the result you are looking for.

You can detect the browser and then apply the style just to Safari for Windows.

See here for how to detect Safari for Windows:

[Detection for Safari Windows with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851954/detection-for-safari-windows-with-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will accept it. It seems though Safari for Windows isn't up to date as it is for Apple products, so I won't go through this trouble.